# How do I use the command line font in java?

Tags: java, fonts, bitmap, cmd, line

I want to make a game with graphics similar to Dwarf Fortress, but I can't find out how to set the font of my game to the standard windows cmd line font. I believe the font is called Terminal, but because it's a bitmap font java doesnt see it...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add more details. Your game is a command-line java app, or swing app or sth else?

Answer (score 1):

The font is Lucida Console, I believe.

Comment: Actually, it's not. Lucida Console looks a bit like it, but its not the same

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, if you right click terminal > settings > font, you will see it can be only Lucida Console or Consolas. I belive by default it is Consolas.